# How to Measure data consumed by an user in Azure sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, monitoring, multiple-users

For an Azure sql server MI, we have multiple external users consuming data,
I would like to know how much data an user is consuming/extracting from the DB?

Can this be checked from,
1.) From SSMS using queries or UI?
2.) Azure portal?

Comment: You want to know how many MB of data per time frame a user is reading?

Comment: Yes, an an user when he reads/writes data from DB how many bytes/MB of data is being read/wrote and number of reads/writes will also do good. I tried joining sys.dm_exec_connections and sys.dm_exec_sessions using session Id where got num_reads, but it seems only records for particular time period will be stored and not entire history.

Comment: Adding MSDN thread for same question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b41a98e-a71e-4982-bcd5-2aaa344af7f3/how-to-measure-data-consumed-by-an-user-in-azure-sql-server-database?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor is the best solution to dig into and investigate this information. Since MI is deployed to an Azure VM it might be possible that perf counter data is exposed and Azure Monitor can provide the insights to client data consumption: Collect data about Azure Virtual Machines

Another option is to enable log analytics for the SQL instance and use Azure Monitor to ingest and analyze the collected log data: View or analyze data collected with Log Analytics log search

There are multiple options for available tools: Azure SQL Database: Monitoring and tuning

If you are unable to track client consumption at the database level, perhaps there is an upstream application that can be leveraged to track connections and MB's transferred and related data points.

Comment: Thank you, i am not familiar with this let me look into it. Right now am trying out to create an extended event session and achieve the same.